# poptorootviewcontroller not calling dealloc methods and viewdidappear method of rootview controller in a sequence

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller with 4 VCs pushed into it. I have a singleton class with a delegate property that is set to the VC which is on top of the stack. I am setting this delegate to nil in the dealloc method of each VC. I am setting the delegate in the viewdidappear method of the rootVC.

When I pop back to root VC from the 4th VC, the sequence of calling the dealloc methods (of all the VCs in stack) and viewdidappear method is following:

```
"FirstVC dealloc called"
"SecondVC dealloc called"
"viewdidappear of root VC is called"
"ThirdVC dealloc called"
```

Now, the issue I am facing is that the delegate gets set to nil even though I am setting it to self in the root VC's viewdidappear method (which is visible from the control flow too). How can I prevent this situation? I want the viewdidappear method to get called once all the VCs are really deallocated.

Thanks,
Obaid

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't predict the order of method calls unless Apple publishes some guarantee of what they are, perhaps you could program the singleton to be defensive by creating a method such as:

```
- (void)removeDelegate:(UIViewController *)oldDelegate;
```

If the delegate matches the specified old delegate, set it to nil.

Answer (score 1):

`dealloc` is called automatically once a object is no longer needed. When you pop the `ThirdVC`, since the delegate property is still retaining it, `dealloc` doesn't get called. Then, when your rootVC's `viewDidAppear` gets called, it sets the `rootVC` as the delegate. At this momment, your thirdVC is no longer needed, which triggers the `dealloc`.

One thing you could do is set the delegate property to nil not on dealloc, but on the `viewWillDisappear` method of each `ViewController`, since this method will surely get called before the next `ViewController` appears.